# How can I prevent specific WordPress Menu Items from appearing to certain User Profiles?

Tags: php, wordpress, menu, menuitem

I am working on a WordPress website, where I would like to prevent specific WordPress Menu Items from being accessible to certain user profiles.  I have managed to prevent the majority of the Menu Items that need to be 'hidden' however, I cannot seem to remove the WordPress Dashboard, WooCOmmerce or Visual Composer.

I have entered the below code, into the `functions.php` but the Menu Items still appear:

```
<?php
function remove_admin_menu_links(){
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    if( $user && isset($user->user_email) && 'name@domain.com' == $user->user_email ) {

    remove_menu_page('index.php');                          // WordPress Dashoboard                                
    remove_menu_page('edit.php?post_type=shop_order.php');  // WooCommerce   
    remove_menu_page('admin.php?page=vc-welcome');        // Visual Composer
    }
}      

add_action('admin_menu', 'remove_admin_menu_links');
?>
```

Is there anything I am doing wrong or is it simply a case that certain WordPress Menu Items cannot be 'hidden'?

**Update**

I have just found out that in order to remove the Visual Composer, as a Menu Item, you need to replace `remove_menu_page('admin.php?page=vc-welcome');` with `remove_menu_page( 'vc-general' );`

That said, this only seems to work for users with the user role 'Administrator'. 
 I am trying to figure out to remove 'Visual Composer' from the 'Shop Manager' Role but yet to figure this out.

Comment: You should better create custom user roles with **User role editor** plugin where you can manage user role capabilities… Then set the correct custom user role for those specific users.

Comment: Ideally, I would prefer to achieve this without a Plugin.  I have managed to 'hide' the other Menu Items, just not WooCommerce and Visual Composer.  Is it possible that these cannot be hidden?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just figured out the problem.

If you are looking to remove the Visual Composer, from a specific User Role, you need to go into the Visual Composer Settings, via the WordPress Dashboard.  The reason for my code, in my question, not working, was because the Visual Composer Plugin Settings were overriding the code in my `functions.php` file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use admin_init hook for remove menu :

```
   add_action('admin_init','remove_admin_menu_links');

function remove_admin_menu_links (){
$user = wp_get_current_user();

    if( $user && isset($user->user_email) && 'name@domain.com' == $user->user_email ) {

        remove_menu_page('index.php'); // WordPress Dashoboard                                
        remove_menu_page('edit.php?post_type=shop_order.php');  // WooCommerce   
        remove_menu_page('admin.php?page=vc-welcome');        // Visual Composer
        }
    }
```

For debug under this function add following line

```
function remove_admin_menu_links (){
$user = wp_get_current_user();

    if( $user && isset($user->user_email) && 'name@domain.com' == $user->user_email ) {
       echo '<pre>';
       print_r($_GLOBALS['menu']);
        }
    }
```

By using above code you will see list of all all menu.
Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Sourabh.  Unfortunately, this did not work.